# How to write a multidiminsional array as tab delimited .txt file in perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, csv

I have a multidimensional array called @main
and I want to write this array into a tab delimited .txt file in perl
Can anyone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 5):

```
open my $fh, '>', "out.txt" or die $!;
print $fh (join("\t", @$_), "\n") for @array;
```

Comment: what happened to the fine art of using special variables? { local $,="\t"; local $\="\n"; print @$_ foreach @h } ($, is the output field separator, and $\ is the output record separator, local is there to avoid polluting the rest of the code)

Comment: @mirod `print @$_` Are you quite sure the array will use the record output separator if you do not double quote the print arg?

Comment: it looks like it, try this (unix): perl -e'@h=( [1,2,3], [4,5,6]); $,="\t"; $\="\n"; print @$_ foreach @h ' (also, in case that wasn't clear, I don't really recommend it ;--)

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there now, when I actually read what you wrote. =P

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that your multi-dimensional array is actually an array of *references* to arrays, since that's the only way that Perl will let you embed an array-in-an-array.

So for example:

```
@array1 = ('20020701', 'Sending Mail in Perl', 'Philip Yuson');
@array2 = ('20020601', 'Manipulating Dates in Perl', 'Philip Yuson');
@array3 = ('20020501', 'GUI Application for CVS', 'Philip Yuson');

@main = (\@array1, \@array2, \@array3);
```

To print them to a file:

```
open(my $out, '>', 'somefile.txt') || die("Unable to open somefile.txt: $!");
foreach my $row (@main) {
    print $out join(",", @{$row}) . "\n";
}
close($out);
```

Comment: Your `@main` should be defined with parens `()` not square brackets. Those make an anonymous array reference.

Comment: @BioLounge: What doesn't work about it? I just tested it and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a multidimensional array, it is an array that was formed by concatenating three other arrays.

```
perl -e '@f=(1,2,3); @g=(4,5,6); @h=(@f,@g); print join("\t",@h)."\n";'
```

Please provide desired output if you want further help.

Answer (score 1):

Two dimensions I hope:

```
 foreach my $row (@array) {
     print join ("\t", @{$row}) . "\n";
 }
```

Perl doesn't have multidimensional arrays. Instead, one of its three native datatypes ia a one dimensional array called a *List*. If you need a more complex structure in Perl, you can use references to other data structures in your *List*. For example, each item in your *List* is a reference to another *List*. The primary list can represent the rows, and the secondary list are the column values in that row.

In the above `foreach` loop is looping through the primary list (the one that represents each row), and `$row` is equal to the ***reference*** to the list that represents the column values.

In order to get a Perl list and not a reference to the list, I dereference the reference to the list. I do that by prefixing it with an `@` sign. I like using `@{$row}` because I think it's a little cleaner than just `@$row`.

Now that I can refer to my list of column values as `@{$row}`, I can use a `join` to create a string that separates each of the values in `@{$row}` with a tab character and print it out.

Answer (score 1):

If "multidimensional" in your question means n > 2, the tab delimited format might be infeasible.

Is this a case where you want to solve a more general problem: to serialize a data structure?

Look for instance, at the YAML Module (install YAML::XS). There is a DumpFile(filepath, list) and a LoadFile(filepath) method. The output will not be a tab-delimited file, but still be human readable.

You could also use a JSON serializer instead, e.g. JSON::XS.